# GitHub pages is not taking latest commit but showing live website from old code

Tags: github, github-pages

[GH Page](https://vikramvi.github.io/Four-card-feature-section/)

[GH Repo](https://github.com/vikramvi/Four-card-feature-section)

If you check latest commit, it clearly has got display grid for both mobile and desktop views, but in dev tool grid itself is not shown in live website.

I'm not understanding why github has not picked up latest commit and refreshed website which is more than 24+ hour old.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not Working in GH but works with VSCode

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/style.css">
```

Working both places ( note DOT in href )

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css">
```

still not sure why was it working in VSCode without DOT ?